# Do you need an Xbox Live Gold subscription to play online with Halo Master Chief Collection on PC?

Tags: pc, halo-the-master-chief-collection

*Halo: The Master Chief Collection* just released on PC, and I want to know something before I buy. Does the game need an Xbox Live Gold subscription to play online on PC?

Comment: [Steam does say you need an XBox Live Account](https://store.steampowered.com/app/976730/Halo_The_Master_Chief_Collection/) so it is a good question if that requirement is forcing Gold subscription for multiplayer (and ruining one of the advantages of Multiplayer on PC)

Comment: No it just forcing to have an Microsoft or a Xbox Live account. You only have to subscibe a Gold account for playing on Xbox Live. You can play for free on Windows/Steam device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
https://www.windowscentral.com/do-i-need-xbox-live-account-play-halo-mcc-pc

> If you want to play games online with other people on your Xbox One, then you'll need to traditionally purchase an Xbox Live Gold subscription for your Xbox Live account. However, this is not the case for Xbox Live games released on other platforms and services — you can play, for example, on your PC for free.

Comment: You just need to have an Xbox Live account. If you don't have one or want to use a new account you have to create an Xbox Live account or a Microsoft account (for free).